# Does AWS allow users to configure which TLS ciphers are used for API connections?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-iam

Ideally I'd like to be able to use [IAM](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) to enforce that all clients performing administrative access on my account are required to connect over TLS with [a strong cipher set](https://cipherli.st/) and use [the latest version of the request signing algorithm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html).

If this is not possible, are there some good reasons why AWS may have chosen to not implement this control?

## What I found in the AWS docs so far

This page in the AWS docs list all the AWS API service administration endpoints and the [request signing](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signing_aws_api_requests.html) algorithms they support:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html

Although this doc mentions whether a service can be accessed over HTTP, HTTP/HTTPS, or HTTPS only, it **does not** mention what TLS [cipher suites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_suite) are supported.

For some products result in exposed HTTP services, there are docs on supported ciphers and how to configure what protocols clients are allowed to use to connect.  For example:

- CloudFront: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/secure-connections-supported-viewer-protocols-ciphers.html
- ELB: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-security-policy-table.html
- SES: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html

Still, I don't see much telling me whether I can force all API connections that are working with my services to use TLS 1.2+, for example.

The most direct evidence I've found so far is a comment in [the SES docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/security.html) that seems to hint that the SES API specifically does not have such configuration options.

> The Amazon SES HTTPS endpoint supports TLS 1.0 only.

Comment: This is currently not possible on AWS. One likely explanation is that the various teams that build AWS services are disparate and operate pretty much independently, and there hasn't been a very strong driver or motivation to universally implement functionality like what you want, especially since a good number of AWS services are already PCI DSS 3.2 compliant. To get any further information you'd likely have to go through your account rep (if you/your company spend enough on the account).

Comment: @birryree Thanks for that. If you have something that confirms this (a publicly available response from an account rep, for example), I'll accept this as a response.  I will probably follow up with our account rep on this too.  We definitely spend enough to get a response. :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a public response to show/link to - stuff I've learned from account reps is under NDA, and I've also learned a lot about AWS internal workings by talking to some developers who work on the services/libraries. If you get in touch with your account rep, you can definitely make feature requests or ask for an escalation response if you want to get an answer from the engineering team.

Comment: Thanks @birryree. I'll leave this open until we get a response from my end, but everything you said certainly makes sense.